# Is it too late to get the last updates for XP?

Tags: windows-xp, updates

Obviously there won't be any more updates for XP, since they stopped supporting it as of today. However I still have a couple of XP machines around that I don't use much, and they haven't gotten the latest updates that were available. Did they shut off those servers or can you still get the older updates?

Answer (score 2):

No, Microsoft just stopped creating new updates, but the old ones aren't deleted (yet). They still provide the old updates.

Comment: If it works out anything like past versions of Windows, the update system works until access mechanisms (winhttp, BITS) get updated out of existence, root certificates expire or Microsoft quits supporting ancient web browser access on the update servers. The updates aren't suddenly taken down, access to them expires by slow attrition and lack of support. Final support ends up being the Microsoft Download Center until they eventually disappear from there as well. As pointed out, you just don't get new ones as the rtf of misery, jpeg of death and gaping port chasm get reinvented.

Answer (score 0):

@Fiasco Labs; Quite True, in fact I was there today (April 8, 2014) and can still downloads any update desired.
NOTE: MICROSOFT WILL in fact still release security updates for certain versions of WinXP such as Embedded since most bank ATM cash machines and other 'production-critical' devices still run XP...
There is little need for these devices to upgrade to say Win8.1 (most wouldn't meet hardware requirements anyway), as they have little need for end-user services such as Media-Centers, Social Network integration apps, etc. that MS targets the average desktop user with.